# How to Convert Output of listagg() function into XMLTYPE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one stored Procedure `P_FP_GET_PATTERN`.I expect output in following format

```
PATTERN_ID |PATTERN_NAME     | SHIFT
1           Pattern 1         A,B,C,B,A
2           Pattern 2         C,B,A,C
```

[image: OUTPUT OF QUERY]

I'm getting this output in SYS_REFCURSOR `ALL_RESULT_SET`.I need to pass it in XML format.But the moment i put that output in `ALL_RESULT_SET_XML` which is my out parameter of stored procedure of XMLTYPE using `ALL_RESULT_SET_XML:= XMLTYPE(ALL_RESULT_SET);` 
Im getting an error as

```
Error encountered: ORA-31061: XDB error: special char to escaped char conversion failed.
```

I`m getting this error due to column shown using LISTAGG() function.Anybody can please tell me how to handle this ?

My stored Procedure

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE           P_FP_GET_PATTERN
(
    ALL_RESULT_SET_XML  OUT XMLTYPE,
    P_MESSAGE_ALL   OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
V_ERROR  VARCHAR2(2000);
ALL_RESULT_SET SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN 
OPEN ALL_RESULT_SET FOR
SELECT PM.PATTERN_ID ,PM.PATTERN_NAME,
 LISTAGG(SM.SHIFT_NUMBER) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PD.INSTANCE_DAY) "SHIFT"
  FROM T_FP_PATTERN_MASTER PM,
   T_FP_PATTERN_DETAILS PD, 
   T_FP_SHIFT_MASTER SM
 WHERE SM.SHIFT_ID= PD.SHIFT_ID 
   AND PM.PATTERN_ID = PD.PATTERN_ID
GROUP BY PM.PATTERN_NAME,PM.PATTERN_ID;

--Adding output in XML output parameter
ALL_RESULT_SET_XML:= XMLTYPE(ALL_RESULT_SET);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS
THEN
    V_ERROR := SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,1000);
    P_MESSAGE_ALL  := 'Error encountered: '||V_ERROR ;

END;
```

Comment: Maybe you are facing the same problem as described in this post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270445/escaping-control-characters-in-oracle-xdb