# generate xml file from oracle table from store procedure

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I create a store procedure to generate a xml file as per requrie  format
i database table i found special char so its not processing to xml.
how to manage special char for generating XML files, and i want all data of table (facing also clob size issue )
please help here

```
<XML>
    <TABLENAME></TABLENAME>
    <RECORDS>
    <RECORD>
              <COLNAME>AAA</COLNAME>
              <COLNAME>AAA</COLNAME>
    <RECORD>
    <RECORD>
              <COLNAME>AAA</COLNAME>
              <COLNAME>AAA</COLNAME>
    <RECORD>
    <RECORD>
              <COLNAME>AAA</COLNAME>
              <COLNAME>AAA</COLNAME>
    <RECORD>
    <RECORD>
              <COLNAME>AAA</COLNAME>
              <COLNAME>AAA</COLNAME>
    <RECORD>
    <RECORD>
              <COLNAME>AAA</COLNAME>
              <COLNAME>AAA</COLNAME>
    <RECORD>
    </RECORDS>
    </XML> 


<TABLENAME>  = actual table name(case should be same as in database)
<COLNAME> = actual column names from table(case should be same as in database)
Keep other tags as it is. Repeat <RECORD> tag for each row retrieved.


create or replace 
procedure dump_pcd (
   V_TABLE_NAME IN varchar2,
    v_FLAG OUT NUMBER
)
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE
    xt_data xmltype;
    v_ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
    rc_data sys_refcursor;
    v_file  UTL_FILE.file_type;

    BEGIN 
   -- v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MYXML', V_TABLE_NAME ||'.xml', 'A');       
     --  v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MYXML', V_TABLE_NAME || '.xml', 'A');


      v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MYXML', V_TABLE_NAME || '.xml', 'W');
       UTL_FILE.put_line(v_file, '<XML><'||V_TABLE_NAME||'></'||V_TABLE_NAME||'> <RECORDS>');


    OPEN rc_data FOR 
    'select LOG_ID, USER_ID,RUN_DATE,PROCESS,MPOID,MODE_,STATUS,
                  regexp_replace(unistr(NOTES), ''[[:punct:]]'','''') as NOTES,     MARKDELETED from '|| V_TABLE_NAME||'  ';

    v_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newContext (rc_data);
    DBMS_XMLGEN.SETNULLHANDLING(v_ctx,null);

    DBMS_XMLGEN.setrowsettag(v_ctx, 'RECORDS'); 
    DBMS_XMLGEN.setrowtag(v_ctx, 'RECORD');

     xt_data := dbms_xmlgen.getXMLType (v_ctx);
     dbms_xmlgen.closeContext (v_ctx);

    dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(xt_data.getclobval( ), 'MYXML', ''||V_TABLE_NAME||'.xml');
    v_FLAG := 1;


      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
           dbms_xmlgen.closeContext (v_ctx);
            v_FLAG := 0;

      end ;

END dump_pcd;
```

Comment: well, what is this "special char"?

Comment: here i found some char  in table's column are :\ ,<ID>,D: ,09- etc and when i ran below query then i got error 

 select xmlelement("XML",
      xmlconcat(xmlelement(evalname('logfile'), null),
      dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select LOG_ID, USER_ID,RUN_DATE,PROCESS,MPOID,MODE_,trim(STATUS) as STATUS,
                                                 substr(regexp_replace(unistr(NOTES), ''[[:punct:]] '',''''),1,32000) as NOTES, 
                                                 MARKDELETED from logfile where rownum<100 ')))
from dual;

Comment: What error are you getting now? None of those characters should cause a problem like the ORA-31061 you said you were seeing before. ('D:' ?)

Comment: one table column have datatype char(8) and i found error like this Error report:
SQL Error:ORA-31061: XDB error:special char to escaped char conversion failed.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 288
ORA-06512: at line 1 so i use --> regexp_replace(unistr(EA_NUMBER), ''[[:space:]]'','''') as EA_NUMBER
 and some time I found error ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
ORA-30186: '\' must be followed by four hexdecimal characters or another '\'
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 288
ORA-06512: at line 1
19202. 00000 -  "Error occurred in XML processing%s"

Comment: i also found &  and some space but when I has copy data  on notepad then  found some other char/ here i am not able to past. like arrow, <control>