# Alternative FIRST_VALUE/workaround when first_value throws error due to size of varchar value

Tags: sql, oracle

First_value throws error,

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too
>   small due to the big varchar(32767)

I've tried first_value and works fine when input value is small but when it gets bigger, it thorws error.
So I don't think I cannot user first_value like below.

```
SELECT 
ID,
FIRST_VALUE(User) over (partition by id order by date) as firstUser,
FIRST_VALUE(Comment) over (partition by id order by date) as FirstComment,
FIRST_VALUE(User) over (partition by id order by date desc) as lastUser,
FIRST_VALUE(Comment) over (partition by id order by date desc) as LastComment
from table;
```

Is there any alternative way to combine two rows into one.
the query that getting below comment is long running query so want to avoid the run that query twice.

ex.

```
- ID | User | Date | Comment
- 1 | user1 | 2019/06/25 | comment1
- 1 | user2 | 2019/06/26 | comment2
```

Expecting result

```
- ID | firstUser | FirstComment | lastUser | lastComment  
 1 | user1 | comment1 | user2 | comment2
```

Comment: For two of those columns, why not use `last_value()`?

Comment: I know last_value. my question is that  it seems first_value cannot handle the varchar(32767) values. the query above just works fine when the comment value is short.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Comment`?  I would expect it to work with `first_value()`.

Comment: Why would the SQL function `first_value()` throw a PL/SQL error? It might be helpful to show what you are really doing - i.e. a [mre].

Comment: datatype of comment is VARCHAR2(32767).

Comment: Please include your full Oracle version, the table DDL, and all the relevant code - including, it seems, your PL/SQL code

Comment: Is that really your complete query? I very much doubt that it will throw _that_ error. Please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** code that generates the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not be getting such error.

But, If it is the case and you want to follow some other approach then following is the code for you:

```
-- I have used || as a separator.. You can use your own separator, if needed
WITH DATAA (ID1,USER1,DATE1,COMMENT1) AS
(SELECT 1, 'USER1',DATE '2019-06-25','comment1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'USER2',DATE '2019-06-26','comment2' FROM DUAL)
SELECT
    ID1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(USER1, '[^(||)]+') AS FIRSTUSER,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(COMMENT1, '[^(||)]+') AS FIRSTCOMMENT,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(USER1, '[^(||)]+$') AS LASTUSER,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(COMMENT1, '[^(||)]+$') AS LASTCOMMENT
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID1,
            RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, USER1, '||').EXTRACT('//text()')
                ORDER BY
                    DATE1
            ).GETCLOBVAL(), '||') AS USER1,
            RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, COMMENT1, '||').EXTRACT('//text()')
                ORDER BY
                    DATE1
            ).GETCLOBVAL(), '||') AS COMMENT1
        FROM
            DATAA
        GROUP BY
            ID1
    );
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ce5f1ce0e36f9253da2e0d3f5b75fb6)

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for this one. it seems working fine but again when i ran with different input values, it throws ORA-31061: XDB error: special char to escaped char conversion failed.
Can you please guide me where to look into?

Comment: An issue with your data(non-unicode characters). -- [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270445/escaping-control-characters-in-oracle-xdb)