# regexp for all accented characters in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, character-encoding

I am trying to find data that has accented characters. I've tried this:

```
select *
from xml_tmp
where regexp_like (XMLTYpe.getClobVal(xml_tmp.xml_data), unistr('\0090'))
```

And it works. It finds all records where the XML data field contains É. The problem is that it only matches the upper-case E with an accent. I tried to write a more generic query to find ALL data with accented vowels (a, e, i, o, u, upper and lowercase, with any accents) using equivalence classes. I wanted a regex to match *only* accented vowels, but I'm not sure how to get it, as equivalence classes such as `[[=e=]]` match *all* e's (with or without accents).

Also,  this does not actually work:

```
select *
from xml_tmp
where regexp_like (XMLTYpe.getClobVal(xml_data),'É');
```

(using Oracle 10g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more experimenting, I have found that this seems to work ok:

```
select *
from xml_tmp
where regexp_like(XMLTYpe.getClobVal(xml_data),'[^[:graph:][:space:]]')
```

I had thought that `[:graph:]` would include *all* upper and lower case characters, with or without accents, but it seems that it only matches *unaccented* characters.

---

Further experimentation shows that this might not work in all cases. Try these queries:

```
select *
from dual
where regexp_like (unistr('\0090'),'[^[:graph:][:space:]]');
```

```
DUMMY
-------
X
(the match succeeded)
```

So it looks like the character that's been causing me trouble matches this pattern.

```
select *
from dual
where regexp_like ('É','[^[:graph:][:space:]]');
```

```
DUMMY
-------

(the match failed)
```

When I try to run this query with the accented E as copied-and-pasted, the match fails! I guess whatever I copied-and-pasted is actually different. Ugh, I think I now hate working with changing character encodings.

Comment: That's bizarre; the whole reason for `[:graph:]` and its ilk is so as to include non-ASCII characters. This is good to know!

Comment: @ruakh: I've never used `[:graph:]` before so I'm nto sure if this is how it's *supposed* to work or if it's just some strange environmental setting that's causing it to behave this way...

Comment: What's also strange is that I'd tried `regexp_like(xml_data,'[\x80-\xFF]')` and it returned nothing. I thought that would have worked for sure.

Comment: (I got the idea for `[\x80-\xFF]` from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236475/finding-and-removing-non-ascii-characters-from-an-oracle-varchar2 )

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
SELECT *
  FROM xml_tmp
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE
        ( REGEXP_REPLACE
          ( XMLTYpe.getClobVal(xml_tmp.xml_data),
            '[aeiouAEIOU]',
            '-'
          )
          '[[=a=][=e=][=i=][=o=][=u=]]'
        )
;
```

? That will eliminate any unaccented vowels before performing the `REGEXP_LIKE`.

(It's ugly, I know. But it should work.)

Comment: I believe this should work (well, it's missing a comma but I fixed it), although it's been running for several minutes now and then when I tried to kill it PL/SQL Developer hung... Some of the XML objects are rather large... :/