# Issue with LIKE operator in crystal reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'm using LIKE operator in crystal reports to retrieve some records.
For example:

If i use LIKE '*ser*' it should've brought records like this:

'loser'
'losér'
'losêr'
'losër'

But only 'loser' is retrieved, ignoring the rest. If i execute the query on sql management studio, it works normally.

I've found that crystal doesn't accept wildcards the same way as the management studio does...feek free to correct me if i'm wrong here. Is there any workarounds?

I'm using crystal reports 10.

Comment: Have you considered a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)?

Comment: @craig Is there a regex UFL or are you talking about doing this in SQL?

Comment: @Ryan: using the database would be more efficient, but there is also a [UFL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cruflregex/files).  The hardest part is constructing a regex that will allow for variation in vowels.  You might have to explicitly list the Unicode values in the expression.

Comment: If you are using Oracle, this might help: [regexp for all accented characters in Oracle][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020610/regexp-for-all-accented-characters-in-oracle

Comment: I'm using sql server. The thing is...the column that has accented characters is set to be accent_insensitive. But it seems like crystal reports 10 doesn't support this. I created a .ttx file and used it as my database file. Kinda brutal but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
LIKE '*ser*'
```

or

```
LIKE '%ser%'
```

Comment: I've tried the first option but it won't bring accented values.

Comment: you have different "e": ë,é and ê and you are comparing this with a regular "e"

Comment: Tried both still my report is empty

Answer (score 0):

{dbo.VAriable} Like " * " & {?Paramiters} & " * "

Answer (score 0):

since 'e' is different in each of the above strings, you would need to compare it with %sër,%sér and %sêr or you could try '%s%r%'