# ORA-12728: invalid range in regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to check if valid phone number is inserting in table, so my trigger code is here:

```
 select start_index
              into mob_index
              from gmarg_mobile_operators
              where START_INDEX = substr(:new.contact_info,0,3);

              if (REGEXP_LIKE (:NEW.CONTACT_INFO,'^(?:'|| mob_index ||')[\-,\:]{0,1}[0-9][0-9][\-,\:]{0,1}[0-9][0-9][\-,\:]{0,1}[0-9][0-9]')) then
                found := 1;
              end if;
```

I've checked my regex: "^(?:555)[-,:]{0,1}[0-9][0-9][-,:]{0,1}[0-9][0-9][-,:]{0,1}[0-9][0-9]" on several online tools and it is correct.

When I run my trigger, it compiles successfully, but during inserting a row following error is shown:

```
 insert into GMARG_CONTACTS
(CLINET_ID,CONTACT_INFO,contact_type_id)
values
(0,'555194117','Mobile')
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-12728: invalid range in regular expression
ORA-06512: at "HR.GMARG_TRIGGER_CONTACT", line 12
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.GMARG_TRIGGER_CONTACT'
12728. 00000 -  "invalid range in regular expression"
*Cause:    An invalid range was found in the regular expression.
*Action:   Ensure a valid range is being used.
```

So, if my regex is correct, why does oracle shows error? 
I tried to find answer, or redifine my regex, but no forward steps...
thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regexp don't use `\` to protect `-` in a *bracket expression*. You only have to put `-` as the first character, just after the opening bracket:

```
IF REGEXP_LIKE('--,,::', '[\-,:]*')
...

=> ORA-12728: invalid range in regular expression
```

If you're curious, when encountering `[\-,:]` Oracle understand: *"any character in the range from `\` to `,` or the character `:`"*. The reason why this raises an exception is `\` appears to be *after* `,` according to their ASCII value. And Oracle don't accept *range* having a starting value after the ending one.

On the other hand:

```
 IF REGEXP_LIKE('--,,::', '[-,:]*')
```

Works as expected.

---

<sub>As a side note, `[-,:]{0,1}` meaning *"zero or one occurrence of `-` or `,` or `:`"* could be written `[-,:]?`.</sub>

Comment: @GiorgiMargiani Note that this might be true only for oracle. In most other regex engines, you would indeed use a backslash to escape the dash. Then again, it's much safer to simply put the dash at the start/end of a character class.

Comment: @Jerry not _"only for Oracle"_: GNU `grep` interprets `\ ` literally too. And probably other Unix/Linux tools using standard regex. To test, try `echo '\' | grep '[,\-]' && echo ok`