# Remove spaces and UTF while writing hive table into HDFS files

Tags: hadoop, utf-8, hive

I am trying to write the hive table into hdfs file using following queries

```
insert overwrite  directory '<HDFS Location>' select customerid,'\t' ,f1,',', f2,',', f3,',', f4,',', f5 from  sd_cust_product_recomm_all_emailid_model2 WHERE EMAILID IS NOT NULL;
```

I am getting the UTF and spaces in the file . The output is somthing like this :

```
customer1\t^Af1^A,^Af2^A,^Af3^A,^Af4^A,^Af5^A,
```

I desired output in following format

```
customer1/tf1,f2,f3,f4,f5
customer2/tf1,f2,f3,f4,f5
```

with no spaces and UTF

Thanks for the help

Comment: You may be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236475/finding-and-removing-non-ascii-characters-from-an-oracle-varchar2

Answer (score 1):

The default delimiter is the issue. Data written to the filesystem is serialized as text with columns separated by ^A.
By explicitly mentioning the Field delimiter(Comma) and Row delimiter(\n) you can overcome the issue.

> insert overwrite directory '[HDFS Location]'   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  select
>   customerid,'\t',f1,f2,f3,f4,f5 from 
>   sd_cust_product_recomm_all_emailid_model2 WHERE EMAILID IS NOT NULL;