# Replace special characters in Oracle database

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have more than 200 000 data in a table with a column that has a special character 'Æ??` and text is test1234Æ??. How to replace that with '?' symbol?

Comment: The same way as any other letter? That's just a letter used, as far as I know, in Danish and Norwegian.

Answer (score 1):

The Æ has unicode 00C6. Just google "Æ unicode" to find that - with that knowledge, you can then use the `UNISTR` function to represent that character. But you can also just paste that character in your sql as shown below if your client supports the unicode characters.

```
WITH mystrings AS
(SELECT 'found a Æ in this text' as str FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'text is test1234Æ??' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
  REPLACE(str,UNISTR('\00c6'),'?') as clean_string,
  REPLACE(str,'Æ','?') as clean_string2,
  REPLACE(str,UNISTR('\00c6??'),'?') as clean_stringnoqm
  FROM mystrings;

CLEAN_STRING            CLEAN_STRING2           CLEAN_STRINGNOQM       
----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
found a ? in this text  found a ? in this text  found a Æ in this text 
text is test1234???     text is test1234???     text is test1234?
```

If you want to only keep characters in the range a-zA-Z and comma you could use a regular expression. There are plenty of other answers around for that, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236475/finding-and-removing-non-ascii-characters-from-an-oracle-varchar2).

```
WITH mystrings AS 
( SELECT
  'Brand1® is supercool, but I prefer bRand2™ since it supports Æ' AS str
    FROM dual
)
SELECT
  regexp_replace(str,'[^A-Za-z0-9, ]', '?') AS clean_string
  FROM mystrings;
```